# Net Beans "Must set src.dir" error when generating jforms

Tags: netbeans

I have developed a problem, I cannot resolve.

I am running Net Bean 8.2 Build: 201609300101.
I am running it on a Windows 7 platform.

Yesterday Net Bean worked fine and would generate the jforms for me. Last night something happened and I can no-longer build, compile and run jforms classes.

I can generate and run simple Java programs. I wrote a simple program that just prints "Hello" and that worked.

When I generate a jform, everything looks good in the IDE but it will not build or run.

I get the following error:
c:users\Admin\Documents\Netbeans\KensPanel\nbproject\build-impl.xml:899 Must set src.dir.

None of the NetBeans examples work either and they did yesterday.

In reviewing the posts on the NetBeans forum concerning the problem, I found several that suggested looking in "nbproject directory for a project.properties file. in the file there should be a "build.dir = build" statement. It is there.

I have completely deleted the project and rebuilt the program and that did not work.

I uninstalled the NetBeans program, the JDK and the JRE programs and reinstalled them (JDK & JRE first) and that did not fix the problem.

I put a simple print statement "(System.out.println("Hello");" in the "Public Static void Main(String[] args)" function at the bottom of the KensPanel.java file and the program will compile and print out "Hello" but will not bring up the GUI.

I get the feeling the problem is somehow related to the "ANT" process but anything having anything to do with that is way over my head.

As I stated earlier, the program worked yesterday afternoon. Last night, the IDE decided that it did not want to play any more and I have not been able to find the problem. I am at a loss.

I am real new to the program and for that matter, Java in general. I really need help.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer.  At least, I got around the problem.

In the New Java application screen, I had left the "create Main Class" box checked.  I found in the NetBeans tutorial, the tutorial stated that I needed to "un-check" the box. When I did that, at least my application works.  I haven't tried the examples yet.

Moving on to the next learning task.

Ken